# Best way to save a trained model in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I have a model which I have trained and I would like to save it for future use and distributing to others. What is the best way to save a trained model with `Flux.jl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `Flux.jl` docs (https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/saving/) the best way to save a trained model is using [BSON.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/BSON.jl) by doing the following:

```
julia> using Flux

julia> model = Chain(Dense(10,5,relu),Dense(5,2),softmax)
Chain(Dense(10, 5, NNlib.relu), Dense(5, 2), NNlib.softmax)

julia> using BSON: @save

julia> @save "mymodel.bson" model
```

and then you can load the saved model by doing:

```
julia> using Flux

julia> using BSON: @load

julia> @load "mymodel.bson" model

julia> model
Chain(Dense(10, 5, NNlib.relu), Dense(5, 2), NNlib.softmax)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your model does not have things like dynamically created/sized layers, you should be able to save just the weights instead of serializing the whole model. This can be much more robust than using BSON.jl or the Serialization stdlib to serialize the whole model (both of which can be very fragile).

The weights can be obtained from a model by `weights=collect(params(cpu(model)))` and loaded back into the model by `Flux.loadparams!(model, weights)`. Thus, one just needs to save a `Vector` of numeric arrays to disk, instead of more complicated Julia-side objects in the model. So I would suggest a pattern like:

```
function make_model(config)
   ...define layers, put them in a chain, etc...
    return model
end

# train model
...

# collect weights
weights=collect(params(cpu(model)))

# save them to disk somehow...
```

Then when it's time to reload the model,

```
weights = # load them from disk
fresh_model = make_model(config)
Flux.loadparams!(model, weights)
```

Note that this approach means you can't e.g. add a layer to `make_model` and reload old weights; they will no longer be the right size. So you need to version your code and your weights and ensure they match up.

Last week I helped make a new package [LegolasFlux.jl](https://github.com/beacon-biosignals/LegolasFlux.jl) to make this pattern easier (in particular, providing a way to use Arrow to save the weights to disk along with any other configuration parameters, losses, etc, you would like to save). It should be registered in two days.